# How to fetch a Sales Order saved search using a restlet in Netsuite, showing company names instead of company internal IDs

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to fetch the results of a saved search programmatically using a restlet. The saved search is for all open sales and I have set it to show the job number, company and date created. Results look fine in a csv however when I fetch them through a script the company names come as internal ids instead of the actual company names. How can I make so that Netsuite returns the actual company display names. Example script below:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define([
    'N/search',
], function (search) {
    function getSearch() {
        var s = search.load({
            id: "customsearch123",
        });

        var results = [];
        var slice = [];
        var i = 0;
        var resultSet = s.run();
        do {
            slice = resultSet.getRange({ start: i, end: i + 999 });
            slice.forEach(function(row) {
                var resultObj = {};
                row.columns.forEach(function(column) {
                    resultObj[column.name] = row.getValue(column);
                    });
                results.push(resultObj);
                i++;
            });
        } while (slice.length >= 1000);

        return JSON.stringify(results);
    
        
    }
    return {
        get: getSearch
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of row.getValue, use row.getText.